# Enable only Office 365 users to send e-mail to SharePoint list?

Tags: email, office-365, office-integration, incoming-email

We currently have a SharePoint 2010 with a list that can receive e-mails from anyone that has a domain account/e-mail. However, we started to move some users to office 365, and even though there is a federated server, the user is not able to send the e-mail to the SharePoint list.

The question is: Is it possible to only allow the company users (including office 365 users) to send e-mails to the list but block everyone else?

Thank You for reading.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK email enabled lists are not possible with O365.

There are 3rd party products available with that features, see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/onlineservicessharepoint/thread/73673deb-04e8-4a27-a825-fe3b58683135/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but I was wondering about sending the e-mail to a local instance of SharePoint. The SharePoint is not on Office 365 yet.

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible with SharePoint. You could add an exchange rule to drop mails from other senders than O365.